# How do I deploy a program to a vanity address?

Tags: solana-program

It's unclear to me what the flow here should be. Typically I've done a test deploy locally, found the program_id that it was deployed to, and then copied that into the appropriate places.

I'm using Anchor, fwiw.

(I can grind an address, though I'm not sure how to specify program deployment to that address.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the path to your vanity keypair directly to `solana program deploy` with the `--program-id KEYPAIR_PATH` argument

Credit to @trent.sol above

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. You just have to copy your grinded .json key into `./target/deploy/MY_PROGRAM-keypair.json`

Comment: You can also pass the path to your vanity keypair directly  to `solana program deploy` with the `--program-id KEYPAIR_PATH` argument

Comment: What's not immediately obvious is that this keypair isn't needed after the first deploy, ie for upgrades. Only the program upgrade authority is required, which is the key currently in use by the CLI (ie call `solana address` or `solana config get` to see which one).

Comment: @yamen correct.  The keypair is only needed to create the account itself.  Once its created, that keypair hold no authority or capability against the program.  In fact, you'll see some protocols share the program's key in their github.  The upgrade authority is the only signer that matters after initial deploy.